# SOLVED Emacs + Dvorak: C-c C-k bug

Tags: keyboard-layout

If you type `C-c C-k` (to abort a capture process, for example), you get a `C-c C-v` instead. It's like for this particular shortcut combo, Emacs interprets the hard key codes instead of the Dvorak layout on top (FYI: pressing `v` on a standard keyboard produces the key `k` with the Dvorak layout). I think the problem lies with Emacs since even the mini buffer shows it as `C-c C-v`. At any other time, my `k` key works just fine on its own (<s>including any other shortcut other than `C-c C-k`</s> `C-k` generally trenslates to `C-v`).

Have any other Dvorak user encountered this problem? How did you fix this? I want to make sure I'm not the only one, because if I am, it is probably not a bug.

I'm on Emacs 24.5.1.

Update: I just noticed an old piece of Autohotkey script that was mapping Ctrl+k to Ctrl-v. So the problem was Emacs unrelated.

Comment: Do you see the same behaviour when starting Emacs like this: `emacs -q`?  If not, this is related to your settings.  I'm using Dvorak as well and cannot reproduce this.

Comment: It might also be related to how your computer is set up to use Dvorak. Are you using an OS setting? A registry remap? A keyboard with levers to press the QWERTY buttons?

Comment: @rekado: Same behavior with `-q`.

Comment: @zck: I'm using the default "English (United States)"->"United States-Dvorak" layout that comes with Windows 7.

Comment: @zck: Thanks, I solved this (it was a forgotten piece of Autohotkey code still running), you nudged me in the right direction.

Comment: @Certainly The convention used on stackexchange is to mark an answer that resolves your problem as **Accepted**. So instead of editing the title with "SOLVED", you should answer your own question and accept it after 48 hours.

Comment: @kaushalmodi: I'll do that (if I don't forget after 48h).

Comment: @Certainly The first step is to submit your own answer. The 48 hrs wait time is after that. :)